# Prove that $V = W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$ iff each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as $w_{1}+w_{2}$ where $w_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $w_{2}\in W_{2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, direct-sum

Let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$  iff each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as $w_{1}+w_{2}$ where $w_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $w_{2}\in W_{2}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

We are going to prove the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

If $v\in V = W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$, then $v = w_{1} + w_{2}$, where $w_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $w_{2}\in W_{2}$, and $W_{1}\cap W_{2} = \{0\}$.

Assume that $v = w'_{1} + w'_{2}$, where $w'_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $w'_{2}\in W_{2}$. We shall prove that $w_{1} = w'_{1}$ and $w_{2} = w'_{2}$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
v = w_{1} + w_{2} = w'_{1} + w'_{2} \Longrightarrow w_{1} - w'_{1} = w'_{2} - w_{2}
\end{align*}

Therefore $w_{1} - w'_{1}\in W_{1}\cap W_{2}$, that is to say, $w_{1} = w'_{1}$. Similarly, we conclude that $w_{2} = w'_{2}$.

We may now prove the case $(\Leftarrow)$.

If $v\in V$, $v = w_{1} + w_{2}$ according to the given assumption, where $w_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $w_{2}\in W_{2}$.

Since such decomposition is unique, we deduce that $V = W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$.

Indeed, let us assume that $v\in W_{1}\cap W_{2}$. Therefore $v = v + 0 = 0 + v$.

But the decomposition of $v$ is unique. Thus $v = 0$.

Could someone please double-check my reasoning?

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct, although you have a tiny mistake in the first implication, when you rearrange the equality $w_1+w_2=w_1'+w_2'$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your solution is fine. I will give you an alternative solution for the $(\Leftarrow)$ part:

Suppose that $v \in W_1 \cap W_2$. Since $0 = v+(-v) \in W_1 + W_2$ and (obviously) the zero vector also can be written as $0 = 0+0 \in W_1 + W_2$, we conclude that these decompositions are the same. Hence $v = 0$.